# chartjs v4 line breaks into dots after pan or zoom, when new data is added

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I developed a simple app that adds new data to a line graph when a user spans left or right (later I will add data by ajax calls).
When a user spans left or right, line breaks into dots. Line breaking does not start immediately, but only after 3 or more points added.

[An example of line breaking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FsBj.png)

```
<script src="~/js/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js"></script>

<div style="max-width:980px;">
    <div class="chartjs-size-monitor"><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-expand"><div class=""></div></div><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-shrink"><div class=""></div></div></div>
    <canvas id="chart" style="display: block; touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); width: 380px; height: 190px;" width="380" height="190" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>
</div>




<div class="as-console-wrapper"><div class="as-console"></div></div>
@section Scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">
        data = [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40, 43, 42, 21, 43, 34]
        labels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
        const config = {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'My First Datase t',
                    data: data,
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                    tension: 0.1,
                    spanGaps: true
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    x: {
                        offset: false
                    }
                },
                plugins: {

                    zoom: {
                        pan: {
                            enabled: true,
                            mode: 'x',
                            onPanStart: function (chart) {
                                if (chart.event.additionalEvent == 'panleft') {
                                    if (chart.chart.scales.x.max == data.length - 1) {
                                        
                                        data.push(3);
                                        labels.push('r');
                                    }

                                }
                                else {
                                    if (chart.chart.scales.x.min == 0) {
                                        data.unshift(1);
                                        labels.unshift('2');

                                    }
                                }
                                chart.chart.update('none');
                            }


                        },
                        zoom: {
                            wheel: {
                                enabled: true,
                            },
                            pinch: {
                                enabled: true
                            },
                            mode: 'x',
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        window.onload = function () {
            var myChart = new Chart(
                document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d'),
                config);
        };
    </script>
```

Please, give me any advice how to stop line breaking into dots.